# how to configure jetty handler to create a name upon request to download a file

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

we have a very very simplified API that upon request sends a file

Server is:

```
public class Server {
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        // start the server
        System.out.println("starting jetty...");
        final org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server server = new org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server(80);
        server.setHandler(new Handler());
        server.start();
        System.out.println("jetty server has started");

    }
}
```

and the handler:

```
public class Handler extends AbstractHandler {
    @Override
    public void handle(String target, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

            if(target.matches("/get")){
                   File file = getFile(); //assume filename is myFile.zip
                    byte[] bytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);
                    response.getOutputStream().write(bytes);
                    response.flushBuffer();
            }

    }
}
```

when I make a request to `localhost:80/get` from browser it saves the desired file but browser names it `get`

what changes needs to be done so the request will result the file to be saved as `myFile.zip`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a file name like this:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=myFile.xyz");
```

If you want the browser to open a save dialog add attachement:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=myFile.xyz");
```